Does calling Pikmin back to the Onion affect Pikmin in different squads?
In Pikmin 3 Deluxe, when you call Pikmin back to the ship it says "Call Pikmin not in the squad back closer to the Onion?". Does this exclusion only apply to Pikmin in your current squad?
For example, let's say Alph is in the field with his own squad of Pikmin. If I call back the Pikmin while playing as Brittany, will the Pikmin in Alph's squad be called back to the ship?

Image from game8.co

I could not find a definitive answer online so I tried it myself:



The Pikmin will not be called back. Only Pikmin who are not in any squad will return to the landing site.
If you call back Pikmin whose onion has not yet merged with the "main" onion they will move to their respective onion instead of the landing site.
